# code not working in latest react-router-dom in react router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

in react I want to run an application-related react-router; that is fine; the problem is that specific code, such as "react-router-dom": "6.8.1," does not run in the latest react version and throws an error.

> "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
> or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
> likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
> or you might have mixed up default and named imports."

But if you change the version, it's working fine, like in "react-router-dom": "5.2.1", This code is working fine, ,so my question is in "react-router-dom": :6.8.1 How to successfully run that code?in my App.js in code structure which thing should I have to change that code will run perfectly in 6.8.1 too?

```
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  generatePath,
  Switch,
  Route,
  useHistory,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";



const products = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Product 1"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "Product 2"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "Product 3"
  }
];

const Products = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  console.log(id);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Id: {id}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const Home = () => {
  const [id, setId] = useState();
  const history = useHistory();
  console.log(history)
  const handleProceed = (e) => {
    id && history.push(generatePath("/products/:id", { id }));
  };

  return (
    <div
      style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", alignItems: "center" }}
    >
      <div>
        {products.map((product, i) => (
          <button
            key={i}
            onClick={(e) => {
              setId(product.id);
            }}
          >
            {product.name}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
      <button onClick={handleProceed} style={{ width: "250px" }}>
        Click
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header>Heading</header>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/products/:id">
            <Products />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-router@6` brought with it a ton of breaking changes. You should review the [Upgrading from v5](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5) migration guide for the full details.

The `Switch` component was replaced by the [`Routes`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/routes) component which is required to directly wrap `Route`s you are rendering, and the `useHistory` hook was replaced by the [`useNavigate`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate) hook.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  generatePath,
  Routes,
  Route,
  useNavigate,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";
```

`useNavigate` returns a `navigate` function instead of a "history" object. Call `navigate` to issue imperative navigation actions.

```
const Home = () => {
  const [id, setId] = useState();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleProceed = () => {
    navigate(generatePath("/products/:id", { id }));
  };

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        alignItems: "center"
      }}
    >
      <div>
        {products.map((product) => (
          <button
            key={product.id}
            type="button"
            onClick={() => {
              setId(product.id);
            }}
          >
            {product.name}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
      <button
        type="button"
        disabled={!id}
        onClick={handleProceed}
        style={{ width: "250px" }}
      >
        Click
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The `Route` component API/props changed, all the routed content is rendered on the `Route` component's [`element`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#element) prop.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header>Heading</header>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/products/:id" element={<Products />} />
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For React Router v6, `useNavigate` should be used instead of `useHistory` (which no longer exists).

```js
const navigate = useNavigate();
// ...
id && navigate(generatePath("/products/:id", { id }));
```

Comment: till that error is comming after changing usehistory to useNavigate

Comment: @SougataMukherjee There should be a longer stack trace. Did you check the root cause?